# PHP query error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I am using LIKE to do my searching, i try it in phpMyAdmin and return the result but when i use it in php it return empty result.

```
$search = "ip";
$start = 0;
$query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_name LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT $start,30";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(empty($result))
    $nrows = 0;
else
    $nrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

It will return result when i using phpMyAdmin to run this query but when i use it in php, it return empty.

**Update:**

Sorry guys,

I just found out the problem is i didn't connect database as well. anyway, thanks for helping.

Comment: If you check the value of $query, is it identical to what you used in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Did you try to print out `$query` before execute it? Are you sure it's exactly written as you need?

Comment: What does `$search` contain? What does `$start` contain? Also note you will need to sanitize both values to protect against SQL injection http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection

Comment: @pekka +1 for SQL injection care.

Comment: try this `$query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_name LIKE %".$search."% LIMIT $start,30";`

Comment: You haven't returned the result anywhere here in your code.. $results only stores the object of the resultset and you have either user mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_object .. Make sure you included that..

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `product_name` LIKE '%".$search."%' LIMIT 0, 30";
```

Answer (score 0):

And if the sole purpose of your code is to get the number of products with the searched-for name, use `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead of doing a `mysql_num_rows()` on all your data. It will decrease your querytime and the amount of data that is (unnecessarily) fetched.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this is not working, as the query seems to be correct to me. I would like to suggest you writing query this way

> $query = `<<<SQL`
>
> ```
>  SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_name LIKE "%$search%" LIMIT $start,30
> ```
>
> SQL;

please note that there should not be any space or any character after `SQL;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_name LIKE '%" . $search . "%' LIMIT " . (int) $start. ",30";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use directly mysql_num_rows()

but here is right code

$query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_name LIKE '%".$search."%' LIMIT $start,30";

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = "ip";
$start = '0';
$query = "SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_name LIKE '%".$search."%' LIMIT $start,30";
$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
    $nrows = 0;
} else{
    $nrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
}

//use mysql_num_rows($result) instead of empty($result) because in this situation $result is every time not empty so use inbuilt PHP function mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @TobySpeight if you satisfy with my answer edit reply positively. thx bro.